# How to use Dockerfile COPY command to copy files from parent directories

Tags: dockerfile

I am trying to build a Dockerfile image and I am getting an error in the part of COPY command.

The error is

> no such file or directory

The code are as below

```
...
COPY ../../Folder/file1.txt .
COPY ../../Folder/file2.txt .
...
```

Comment: Use the ancestor directory as the directory argument to `docker build`; use a `docker build -f` option to point at the Dockerfile, if you don't also move it to that ancestor directory; and make the `COPY` paths relative to that ancestor directory.  Leading `..` on the left-hand side of `COPY` just get dropped.  The linked question has a couple of examples.

Comment: Found a solution so the / is very important in the last part of the COPY command. It should be COPY ../../Folder/file1.txt ./